# FQL Your statement is not indexable, but fine in console

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using this query for FQL:

```
SELECT pid, object_id, caption, like_info, comment_info, src, src_small, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE album_object_id="10151088306597851" ORDER BY like_info DESC
```

which works fine in the console, check: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20pid%2C%20object_id%2C%20caption%2C%20like_info%2C%20comment_info%2C%20src%2C%20src_small%2C%20src_big%2C%20images%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20album_object_id%3D%2210151088306597851%22%20ORDER%20BY%20like_info%20DESC

But when I use the Javascript SDK with FB.api() method it fails with error 604 "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql"
But according to the docs of table "photo" "album_object_id" IS indexable..

This is my Javascript code:

```
    if (album_object_id) {
        var query = 'SELECT pid, object_id, caption, like_info, comment_info, src, src_small, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE album_object_id="' + album_object_id + '" ORDER BY like_info DESC';
        //console.log(query);return;
        FB.api('/fql?q=' + encodeURI(query), callback);
    }
```

When I log query and copy/paste it into the graph API console, it works fine..

Any clues??

cheers
Sjoerd

Comment: Can you show the JS code too, please? Are you maybe inserting the album_object_id value dynamically, and that failed or something (f.e. empty value)?

Comment: I've just edited my question and pasted my JS code into the topic

Comment: PS rather than encoding the query yourself, you can also use this syntax: FB.api('/fql', { q: "SELECT..." } (I'll be surprised if your issue is because of an encoding problem, but give it a shot anyway)

Comment: No wait, that's exactly it. Let me put a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a query encoding issue introduced by encodeURI on this syntax. The following code works perfectly and returns 82 items:

```
var query = 'SELECT pid, object_id, caption, like_info, comment_info, src, src_small, src_big, images FROM photo WHERE album_object_id="10151088306597851" ORDER BY like_info DESC';

FB.api('/fql', {q: query}, function(r) {
        console.log(r)
    });
}
```

Comment: ...and, just for completeness, the root cause of the issue is that you were using encodeURI which didn't encode the '=' in your WHERE clause correctly. Using encodeURIComponent instead *does* work, but you should probably use the object literal syntax above instead.