# Get all Photos from facebook album Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Hi guys I want to fetch all the data from user Facebook album. I run the query :-

```
SELECT src_big, caption, src_small, src FROM photo WHERE owner = OWNER_ID AND aid = 'ALBUM_ID'
```

I got following error :-

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

Please see sceenshot :-

[image]

When I Searched I got this solution [FQL Your statement is not indexable, but fine in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028526/fql-your-statement-is-not-indexable-but-fine-in-console) but it doesn't work

**EDIT :-** I tried following code

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => 'APP_ID',
     'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
     'cookie' => true,
));

$fql = "SELECT aid FROM album WHERE aid = 'ALBUM_ID' ";

$response = $facebook->api(array(
     'method' => 'fql.query',
     'query' =>$fql,
));

print_r($response);

?>
```

But it returns empty array `Array()`

**EDIT 1 :-**

I tried below things also

Query :- `SELECT pid,src_big,owner,link,position,created,caption,src FROM photo WHERE aid="ALBUM_ID"`

[image]

**EDIT 2 :-**

I tried following code and I am getting all the images but the problem is when I am using my friends ownerid then it return result but when I use my id then it returns empty why ?

```
<?php
ob_start();
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => 'APP_ID',
     'secret' => 'SECRET_KEY',
     'cookie' => true,
));

$fql = "select aid,cover_pid,description,created,name,photo_count from album where owner=OWNER_IDorder by created desc limit 10";

$result = $facebook->api(array(
'method'=>'fql.query',
'query'=>$fql
));

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($result);$i++){
$fql = "select images,created,link,pid,src_big,src_big_width,src_big_height from photo where aid='".$result[$i]['aid']."'";

$ret = $facebook->api(array(
'method'=>'fql.query',
'query'=>$fql
));

for($j=0;$j<sizeof($ret);$j++){
echo '<img src="'.$ret[$j]['src_big'].'"></img> ('.$ret[$j]['created'].')';
echo '<br>';
}

echo '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------<br><br>';
}
?>
```

where I am doing wrong please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As It was a permission issue of Facebook so I solve this issue by asking users to allow to get access of his/her profile,photos etc and if user accept it then by using following code I can get his Facebook photos.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require 'facebook.php';
    @session_start();
    include_once('config.php');

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => APP_ID,
     'secret' => SECRET_KEY,
     'cookie' => true,
    ));

$fql = "select aid,cover_pid,description,created,name,photo_count from album where owner=me() order by created desc limit 10";

$result = $facebook->api(array(
'method'=>'fql.query',
'query'=>$fql
));

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($result);$i++){
$fql = "select images,created,link,pid,src_big,src_big_width,src_big_height from photo where aid='".$result[$i]['aid']."'";

$ret = $facebook->api(array(
'method'=>'fql.query',
'query'=>$fql,
'scope'=>'user_photos'
));

$k = 1;
for($j=0;$j<sizeof($ret);$j++){


echo '<div>';
echo '<img src="'.$ret[$j]['src_big'].'" id="img'.$k.'"></img>';
echo '<input type="checkbox" class="select_img" current_check = "'.$k.'" name="image_checkbox">';
echo '</div>';

$k++;

}

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you tried your query in the Graph API explorer with **Graph API**; you should rather test it in the **FQL Query** console.

[image]

Second thing, I'm not really show how to get the `aid`, but it is not really the album id you get from the facebook api. Its the `album_object_id` that you should use in your query to get the photos.

You your query would be:

```
SELECT src_big, caption, src_small, src FROM photo WHERE owner = OWNER_ID AND album_object_id = 'ALBUM_ID'
```

P.S. I tried it in the FQL Explorer and it worked fine!

Comment: Milttal Thanks for your reply I tried above code on "FQL Query" tab but it returns no data

Comment: can you tell me from the url of facebook album which is ownerid and which is album_object_id ?

Comment: Try `/me/albums` in graph API explorer, you'll get the `album_object_id` and the owner id is your own (owner's) facebook id. PS dont forget to accept/mark the ans if it helped!

Comment: btw, how did you get his `aid`?

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2, I am getting images from album but when i use my id it returns empty why ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when i use my id it returns empty"? I think if you are getting the images, the problem is solved, right?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that you are not able to fetch the albums of yourself. If this is the case, there could be 2 possible reasons- 
1. you may not have granted `user_photos` permissions, or
2. your fb_id may be  to long for an integer range, so you should ideally use : `owner="OWNER_ID"` (in quotes) not `owner=OWNER_ID`

Comment: when i use ownerid = 146540768824251 it returns images but when i use ownerid = 100001671036014 it returns empty result

Comment: i thinks it permission issue. How can set the permission to upload images using facebook album